# two PHP sessions, same IP address, active at the same time?

Tags: php, ip-address

Is it possible to have two sessions associated with the same IP address active at the same time?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever tried to access gmail, facebook, ... with two different browsers in a same computer you see that you can and if you sign out of one the other one is still signed in meanwhile you have the same IP Address(network layer of TCP/IP) on both browsers(application layer of TCP/IP).